# How to accumulate and retain records in Buffer[] - in a MQL4 Custom Indicator?

Tags: buffer, mql4

I am making a custom indicator, that displays the change in the closing price of a certain currency.

```
for ( i = limit; i >= 0; i-- ) {  
      totaleur = 0;
      for ( x = i; x < i + 1; x++ ) {
            totaleur = ( ( iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x     )
                         - iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x - 1 )
                           )
                         / iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x - 1 )
                           );
      }
      ExtMapBuffer1[i] = totaleur;
      return(0);
}
```

in this case the indicator displays only the change in price of each observation.

Any ideas how to make it display the change in an observation plus all previous observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several important points to realise, so as to make the goal achieved:

### 1: do not prematurely escape in the first round, via `return(0)`

moving the command **`return(0);`** outside the code-execution block `{...}`
from the forward-stepping ( **`i`** decreases ) **`for( i = limit ;...; i--){...}`** code-execution block will let the pointer step forward in `(i)`,
as the Custom Indicator uses a progressive, discontinuous, per-partes incremental ( in time ), evaluation ( ref. MQL4 documentation on Custom Indicator **`iCustom(...)`** calling interface parameters )

### 2: decide, whether the inner-loop <sub>( a sum of fractions )</sub>  was correctly coded

the proposed expression provides
a sum of **`N`**, per-Bar relative differences,
not
a sum of **`N`** absolute-differences, divided by a net price change over `N` bars.

While this might be working, the point is, whether the intended model is correct to sum relative differences ( percent change over different, variable individual bases ), or whether the sum ob absolute differences ought be only at the very end of the loop divided by a one, common, base -- the net price difference between the first and the last point ( over the `N`-bars base ), which is commonly a quantitative modelling practice when a noisy signal is subject to some cheap smoothing technique.

### 3: correct problems in accessing TimeSeries vectors  <sup>( negative index )</sup>

given the outer **`for ( i = limit; i >= 0; i-- )`** loop permits the **`i`** to become zero,
given the inner **`for ( x = i; ... )`** thus permits **`x == 0`**,
the **`x - 1 < 0`** becomes a problem,
where
the instruction **`iClose( _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, x - 1 )`** requests to access a value, that does not yet exist ( has a negative index into TimeSeries vector ).

```
 for ( i  = limit; // SET:_______________________ START at  BAR[i == limit]
       i >= 0;     // PRE:                        PRE-CONDITION i >= 0
       i--         // UPD:                        POST-UPDATE   i-- STEP FORWARD IN TIME
       ) {         // ___________________________________________________________
       totaleur = 0;     // ZEROISED
       for ( x  = i;     // SET:_________________ START at  BAR[x = (i)]
             x <  i + 1; // PRE:                  PRE-CONDITION x < (i)+1
             x++         // UPD:                  POST-UPDATE   x++    +1 STEP ( ONCE ) 
             ) {         // _____________________________________________________
             totaleur = ( ( iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x     )
                          - iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x - 1 )
                            )
                          / iClose( "EURUSD", 0, x - 1 )
                          );
       }                 // LOOP KEPT STORING ANY INTERIM VALUE FOR EACH x INTO THE SAME <var>
       ExtMapBuffer1[i] = totaleur;
       return(0); //___________________________________DO NOT PREMATURELY RET/EXIT RIGHT FROM THE 1st LOOP
}
```

As you might have already noticed, the code permits just one loop in the inner `for(){...}`

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply

Comment: Indeed, but the problem that I still can't upvote because I have less then 15 reputations so adding a comment was the only option for me to acknowledge your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sum of N previous observations - you need something like this:

```
for(i=limit; i>=0; i--) {  
   double totaleur = 0;
   for(x=i; x<i+N; x++) {
      totaleur += ((iClose("EURUSD", 0, x)- iClose("EURUSD", 0, x-1))/iClose("EURUSD", 0, x-1));
   }
   ExtMapBuffer1[i]=totaleur;
}
```

when you have `return(0);` inside loop - indicator will stop there and do not run that cycle with next parameter - so be careful with it

Comment: it seems that N did the trick, thanks. So you mean with `return(0);` the indicator will not process the new  live data?
I've tried to remove it and I receive a warning 
"not all control paths return a value" is it normal?

Comment: yes, move that outside the loop, it must stay at the end of `start()` function - as `user3666197` mentioned